# Help on iTunes Connect

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

Greetings to all,

I am trying to implement in app purchases and still finding difficulty to get it working..since i get invalid product identifiers as response.

In this case, i am having a doubt,

in the iTunes to get it working on in app purchases, i have created a paid app contract but i have not provided any bank information or tax related information - Pls Refer the image..

Do i need to provide bank and tax related information for getting the valid product identifiers on iTunes connect ...

Kindly guide me out and thanks for your time

[image]

Comment: Exact same situation here... would love to hear others' experience.

Answer (score 0):

According to this post: http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/invalid-product-ids/ and this comment there: http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/invalid-product-ids/#comment-2149 your bank/tax info does in fact have to be in iTunes for in-app purchases to work.